# How to cache the data from post request

Tags: ios, networking

The API request is both post ,I wanna cache the data so as to reduce to load the same data per time.Now I have no idea, pls give me some advices about it .I know I can cache the data if the request is GET....

Comment: Your question is unclear.Its like a lion is in front of you and you don't know what you are saying.

Comment: I  send POST REQUEST to server and then receive the response ,I wanna cache the data so as to reduce the same data loading per time ,

Answer (score 0):

**You can cache the response for any type of request:**

**Steps are below**

- First, You has to save response in share instance class.
- Whenever you want to hit the API then first check that you have a pre-response that you have saved last in share instance class. If yes then show this response and update response on the success of API. No need to show loading.

Comment: What's its shortcoming ???I know set all request as Post is a good way...